# EntityFramework: Can we minimize sorting code

Tags: entity-framework

i am fetching data from db using EF. when i fetching then i am filtering and sorting data too.this way i am sorting by column name. huge line i have to write which looks not good.

```
    switch (SortColumn)
    {
        case "CompanyName":
            ViewBag.OldSort = "CompanyName";
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.CompanyName);
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
            }
            else
            {
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName);
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
            }
            break;

        case "ContactName":
            ViewBag.OldSort = "ContactName";
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactName);
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
            }
            else
            {
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.ContactName);
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
            }
            break;

        case "ContactTitle":
            ViewBag.OldSort = "ContactTitle";
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactTitle);
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
            }
            else
            {
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.ContactTitle);
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
            }
            break;

        case "Address":
            ViewBag.OldSort = "Address";
            if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
            {
                customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.Address);
                ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
            }
            else
            {
                customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.Address);
                ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
            }
            break;

        case "Default":
            ViewBag.OldSort = "CompanyName";
            customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName);
            ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
            break;
    }
```

please see for 4 columns i have to write so many line of code. suppose if i need to work with 40 columns then how many more line i need to write. so tell me best option to minimize the code for sorting when working with EF.

### EDIT

see my full working code where full code given to see what approach i take to sort and fetch data with filter. now tell me how could i minimize the code for sorting, filtering with fetching data.

```
private CustomersEntities db = new CustomersEntities();
        public int recordcount = 0;

        // GET: Customers
        public ActionResult Index(int? page, string SortColumn, string CurrentSort, String SearchText)
        {
            var customer = (from s in db.Customers
                            // select s;
                            select new CustomerDTO
                            {
                                CustomerID = s.CustomerID,
                                CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                                ContactName = s.ContactName,
                                ContactTitle = s.ContactTitle,
                                Address = s.Address
                            });

            int pageSize = 5;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            ViewBag.CurrentPage = pageNumber;
            SortColumn = String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortColumn) ? "CompanyName" : SortColumn;
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = SortColumn;
            //ViewBag.OldSort = CurrentSort;
            ViewBag.SearchText = SearchText;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText))
            {
                customer = customer.Where(s => s.CompanyName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
                || s.ContactName.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
                || s.ContactTitle.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper())
                || s.Address.ToUpper().Contains(SearchText.ToUpper()));
            }

            switch (SortColumn)
            {
                case "CompanyName":
                    ViewBag.OldSort = "CompanyName";
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.CompanyName);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName);
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
                    }
                    break;

                case "ContactName":
                    ViewBag.OldSort = "ContactName";
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactName);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.ContactName);
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
                    }
                    break;

                case "ContactTitle":
                    ViewBag.OldSort = "ContactTitle";
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.ContactTitle);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.ContactTitle);
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
                    }
                    break;

                case "Address":
                    ViewBag.OldSort = "Address";
                    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderByDescending(m => m.Address);
                        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.Address);
                        ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
                    }
                    break;

                case "Default":
                    ViewBag.OldSort = "CompanyName";
                    customer = customer.OrderBy(m => m.CompanyName);
                    ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
                    break;
            }

            IPagedList<CustomerDTO> oCustomer = customer.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
            return View(oCustomer);
        }
```

Comment: you could do it with reflection or a custom sql-clause without using the fluent syntax. (to be honest, reflection will be a dirty solution). Personally I'd use a strategy pattern for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewBag.OldSort = SortColumn;

var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");
var exprProp = Expression.Property(arg, SortColumn);
var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, string>>(exprProp, arg);

if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
{
    customer = customer.OrderByDescending(projection);
    ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
    ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
}
else
{
    customer = customer.OrderBy(projection);
    ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i do not understand following 3 lines. please explain more as a result i can understand `var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "x");
var exprProp = Expression.Property(arg, SortColumn);
var projection = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, string>>(exprProp, arg);`

Comment: see my edit area where i have given my full working code to see what approach i have taken to sort and fetch data with filter. now tell me how could i minimize the code for sorting, filtering with fetching data.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar, first three lines are needed to **dynamically** build `projection`, like `m => m.CompanyName` or `m => m.ContactName`, so you can collapse `switch - case` section to neat code, showed above. And what exactly code from **EDIT** section you also want to refactor?

Answer (score 0):

### 1st approach

Assuming all of your sortable columns are strings:

```
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Expression<Func<Customer, string>>> SortColumns = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Customer, string>>>
{
    ["CompanyName"] = c => c.CompanyName,
    ["ContactName"] = c => c.ContactName,
    ["ContactTitle"] = c => c.ContactTitle,
    ["Address"] = c => c.Address,
};

...

if (SortColumns.TryGetValue(SortColumn, out var sortProperty))
{
    ViewBag.OldSort = SortColumn;
    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
    {
        customer = customer.OrderByDescending(sortProperty);
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
        ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
    }
    else
    {
        customer = customer.OrderBy(sortProperty);
        ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
    }
}
else
{
    customer = customer.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName);
    ViewBag.OldSort = "CompanyName";
    ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
}
```

### 2nd approach

That gets slightly more complicated.

Start by adding the necessary using directives:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

Next, you'll need a method to sort based on a LambdaExpression:

```
private static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, LambdaExpression keySelector, bool descending)
{
    string methodName = descending ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
    Type[] typeArguments = { typeof(TSource), keySelector.ReturnType };
    var query = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), methodName, typeArguments, source.Expression, keySelector);
    return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(query);
}
```

Then you'll need to update the dictionary to store LambdaExpression values. To do that cleanly, you'll need a helper method to convert an anonymous delegate to a LambdaExpression:

```
private static LambdaExpression Expr<TProperty>(Expression<Func<Customer, TProperty>> fn) => fn;

private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, LambdaExpression> SortColumns = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>
{
    ["CompanyName"] = Expr(c => c.CompanyName),
    ["ContactName"] = Expr(c => c.ContactName),
    ["ContactTitle"] = Expr(c => c.ContactTitle),
    ["Address"] = Expr(c => c.Address),
};
```

And finally, update your sorting code to use the new method:

```
if (SortColumns.TryGetValue(SortColumn, out var keySelector))
{
    ViewBag.OldSort = SortColumn;
    if (SortColumn.Equals(CurrentSort))
    {
        customer = OrderBy(customer, keySelector, true);
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = "";
        ViewBag.SortOrder = "desc";
    }
    else
    {
        customer = OrderBy(customer, keySelector, false);
        ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
    }
}
else
{
    customer = customer.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName);
    ViewBag.OldSort = "CompanyName";
    ViewBag.SortOrder = "asc";
}
```

Now we can sort by any property type.